# White spaces omitted automatically in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to print a string that is passed from a model object in the JSP view. My String is in the form

```
 String str=  "    |    | ";
```

However when i try to print this str using the model object in the JSP view page, the white spaces are omitted i get '||' instead of the original

Any suggestion to keep the original formatting while getting output in HTML in the browser from JSP page?

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: out.println(obj.getSentance()[6]); . Here getSentence returns an array of strings and i am just printing one specific one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not JSP doing it.  In HTML when multiple whitespaces follow each other it only displays one of them, unless you wrap `<pre></pre>` around it, or use `&nbsp;` in place of spaces.  View source in browser and you'll see the spaces are there, its just the browser doesn't display them.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `&nbsp;` for single space.

```
    String str=  "    |    | ";

    str = str.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

---

Have a look at [6 Ways to Insert Spaces in HTML](http://www.wikihow.com/Insert-Spaces-in-HTML)